# disable focus when activity starts

Tags: java, android

I am working on an application that have a login activity with two edit text and a button. when activity starts first edit text is focused and cursor is blinking. I want to stop this and tried to focus on button with this code in onstart,onresume,oncreate but did not worked:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    btn_login.requestFocus();
    super.onStart();
}
```

What can I do?

Comment: @FireSun He has stated that he already tried that.

Comment: Maybe you can elaborate on your question slightly? It is still very unclear, why do you need the focus on the `Button` and not on the `EditText`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would move the code to `onCreate()` and then try something like this:

```
btn_login.setFocusable(true);
btn_login.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
btn_login.requestFocus();
```

You will also want to make sure that the `EditText` is not forcing the keyboard to open with this line:

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Comment: No problem, any time!